# beautiful soup not getting downloaded

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

When I try downloading BeautifulSoup, it is not downloading in a compressed folder and i'm not sure of the format it is in. I have tried downloading all the versions, but thy all result in the same thing.

The picture is attached below.

Comment: There is no picture. Describe in words how you downloaded this, or if you are using commandline (which you should), copy-paste the commands

Comment: Where is the picture .. ?? bro ??

Answer (score 1):

You Can Download ( `beautifulsoup4 4.6.0` ) It From Below Link **Directly Download Package**.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4

Or 
For **Command Line** .. Follow THis **Steps**

http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/beautifulsoup/beautifulsoup-4-python

**Steps:**

> If you run Debian or Ubuntu, you can install Beautiful Soup with the
>   system package manager

```
apt-get install python-bs4
```

> Beautiful Soup 4 is published through PyPi, so if you can’t install it
>   with the system packager, you can install it with easy_install or pip.
>
> The package name is beautifulsoup4, and the same package works on
>   Python 2 and Python 3.

```
easy_install beautifulsoup4

pip install beautifulsoup4
```

> If you don’t have easy_install or pip installed, you can download ( https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/download/4.0/ ) the Beautiful
>   Soup 4 source tarball and install it with setup.py.

```
python setup.py install
```